# Boot native Windows7 install in KVM

Tags: windows-7, virtualization, kvm-virtualization

I have native installed and working Windows7.

When I try to boot it as

```
sudo kvm -hda /dev/sda
```

it shows BSOD `0x0000007B` even if I try to Safe Boot mode.

Same problem using

```
kvm -drive file=/dev/sda,index=0,media=disk,if=ide 
kvm -drive file=/dev/sda,index=0,media=disk,if=virtio
```

(virtio driver are installed in win7)

WindowsXP was working using this schema. What's wrong? What can be made to have it working as bare boot, as KVM boot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your windows lacks the ide and virtio drivers, and fails to boot. try to start it up, add the required drivers, and then run it under kvm

Comment: It looks like the OP says the virtio drivers *are* installed in the question.

Comment: haven't done this in a while, but iirc, there was more than just installing a driver required - some registry hack that would make windows think this driver should be used at boot. The way virt-v2v inserts drivers, you know?

Comment: Thanks for info about v2v! http://libguestfs.org/virt-v2v/ -- looks to be i need p2v, and that helps.